# I cant execute my firefox in kiosk mode in first plan

Tags: firefox, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi4, kiosk-mode

I'm working on a Django project using a Raspberry Pi 4 Model B, and I want Firefox to launch automatically when the machine is turned on, but it always opens in kiosk mode and never comes to the foreground.

Could someone help me with this? Thanks! ^^

I tried with xtool and another things, but it doesnt show in first plan.
The code I have is in the autostart file located in the .config folder.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Firefox Kiosk Mode
Exec=sh -c "firefox --kiosk 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/index/' & sleep 10; wmctrl -a 'Firefox'"
```

Comment: I'm not sure if chromium would be a good alternative for you, but I've created a server image with a kiosk browser starting up automatically - [take a look here](https://github.com/scramjetorg/pi-gen?tab=readme-ov-file#kiosk-image). You can build the whole operating system with just the browser. If that's a solution for you I can write a proper answer.